# Image in Django Template doesn't appear

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I'm trying to use an image in my local server in  a html file. But the image is not found.

This is the path for the image(copy and paste from Mac Get Infor):
/Users/filipeferminiano/Pictures/teste.jpg

And my code:

I'm using Django.

This are my settings:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "static", "static-only")


STATIC_URL = "/static/static-only/"

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "static"),
]
```

Comment: what do you have in your template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shoud define MEDIA_ROOT in your settings file:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'appl_name/Static').replace('\\', '/'))
```

your images must be in appl_name/Static/Pictures/ dir

you template should look like this:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src = {% static 'Pictures/teste.jpg' %} />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your base folder for your django project you usually want to have a "media" or "static" folder. Here you will save your images. Then in settings.py define STATIC_ROOT = 'static' . define STATIC_URL = '/static/' . and finally in your HTML IMG tag define it as such `<img src="{% STATIC_URL %}example_image.jpg >` . that should work n fix ur image problem.